# Why doesn't Retrofit get a faster response after the first request?

Tags: android, postman, retrofit, retrofit2, httpurlconnection

I am doing some research on Retrofit and AsyncTask.
I write a simple code that use AsyncTask + HttpUrlConnection to send a `GET` reuest to  [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) to retrive some json sample. And the respond time look something like below:

- First  response time: 697
- Second response time: 176
- Third  response time: 175

We can see that the response is **getting faster** after the first request.
Which is normal I think, because when I use Postman trying the same thing, it shows the same way. It seems that the server side might cache the result in order to respond faster to the client.

However, when I use Retrofit the result looks like this:

- First  response time: 691
- Second response time: 642
- Third  response time: 636

It seems like the response speed is stable, the second and third one didn't get any faster. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Which is normal I think, because when I use Postman trying the same thing, it shows the same way.` i don't think you can say it's normal because another piece of software does the same thing as what you're wanting

Comment: @a_local_nobody thank you for pointing that out. My main purpose is to figure out what cause the different behavior between these two methods. Could you help me with that?

Comment: async tasks are deprecated so i don't have much experience with them, do you have or have you tried actually adding in cache to retrofit ?

Comment: There are so many factors here...  First you should profile your client code so you can understand where it's spending its time.  Are you deserializing in Retrofit but not with the HttpUrlConnection?  Retrofit will spend some extra time creating object instances. There there is caching... the API is proxied by CloudFlare, maybe you're getting data from their cache after the first request?  Then connections: is HttpUrlConnection requesting `Connection: keep-alive` and using the same connection pool?

Comment: There is also: Compression! I see in my browser  the`content-encoding: br` header which means the server sent a compressed data stream.  Maybe Retrofit didn't send `Accept-Encoding` header with a compression type (gzip, br, etc)?  Less bytes = faster.  You need to understand the minute details of your HTTP request/response exchanges to see if the server is taking longer because of how your request was sent.  The good news is: after doing all this you will have a greater understanding of code performance and the HTTP protocol; that will be super useful in your career.

Comment: tl;dr we can't tell you exactly without seeing your code and understanding your client environment.  You need to drill down into your code and the HTTP protocol.  You can profile your code using Android Studio. See https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler  These types of performance issues are real-world problems that software engineers are expected to solve as part of their work.  You got this.